# How to echo commands in a bash shell script, but not execute them?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

Is there a way for running a shell script with echoing the commands *but* w/o actually executing them?

Let's say I have script removing a file whose name is stored in a variable:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -v
FN="filename"
rm -f ${FN}
```

Adding `set -v` will echo the following commands before execution:

```
$ ./scr.sh
FN="filename"
rm -f ${FN}
```

Now, I want to see the flow of this script w/o actually removing the file. IOW, I want to prevent any effect on the external environment and filesystem. Is this possible?

I could wrap all commands with an `echo` command, but it is tiring for a long script.

Comment: I'm not a bash-scripting expert, but if I would write this with another programming language, I would store all commands in an array. this way it should be easy to loop through and either execute the commands or print the out.

Answer (score 9):

There's no way to step through a script to see how it would execute without actually doing that.  In your example, there are no `if` statements or loops.  But in real scripts, there are often lots of conditional statements.  Which branch will get taken will often depend on what happened when the shell ran the previous command.  If it doesn't run the command, there's no way for the shell to know what output it would have generated or what the return code would have been, which the next conditional branch or assignment statement might depend on.

If the point is that you'd like to scrutinize a script and know what it does before you run it, that's not a bad idea.  But realistically, about the best way to do that is by just browsing the file with `less` or `vi` or something similar.

**Added**

If you're developing a script and you're wanting to step through it the first time, testing the logic but not actually doing any damage if you've got a bug, the solution I'm often able to use is to modify only the statements that could do any damage by pasting an `echo` onto the front.

This often works in typical real-life scripts because (a) generating the lists of items you'll iterate over or the value to which you'll set a variable can often be generated without changing the filesystem and (b) it's usually sufficient to assume that if you did run the command, it would succeed.

Comment: Thanks. It would surprise me if there is a way, exactly due to the reason you mentioned, but I decided to give it a try anyway. The reason for this is that I am developing a script that moves files across many machines in a network and performs some actions on the remote hosts. I'd like to see a flow of the script before actually committing the changes to the filesystem(s). It would be just as tedious to go over all the remote machines to correct file errors...

Comment: An addition:  To step through the script, you can start the script with `trap read debug` which will do a read after every executed line, and you can then step through it slowly with enter (this is useful if you have a really long script and want to test it for the first time).

Answer (score 9):

I think you are going to have to echo - however if you put the command in a variable you can turn it on and off.  Also, the command can be a function and as sophisticated as you want.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Debug'
  D=echo
  :>| testy
  ls -l testy
  $D rm -f testy
  ls -l testy
echo $'\n\nLive'
  D=
  :>| testy
  ls -l testy
  $D rm -f testy
  ls -l testy
```

==================================================

```
!$ > ./conditional.sh
Debug
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nobody nobody 0 2013-01-18 15:28 testy
rm -f testy
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nobody nobody 0 2013-01-18 15:28 testy

Live
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nobody nobody 0 2013-01-18 15:28 testy
ls: cannot access testy: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I required quotes in the echo/don't-echo commands, and then had to use `D=eval` in the live part. But nice answer!

Answer (score 5):

You an trace the flow using the -x option for bash, but this would still execute the commands.

The best you could do is to just put echo or comment out the commands that have external effects like the rm.  At least you wouldn't have to change every line.

Comment: Thanks. I mentioned that option in my question, but it does not really solve my problem.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you meant echoing every line, -x would reduce this to a few commands and show you the evaluations.

Answer (score 4):

I do not know any particular method for dry run, but we can use some precautions for understanding an unknown script.

1. Use a **chroot** environment to run your debug script. It will act as a sandbox and will provide protection against deleting/modifying main system files.
2. Use `bash -n <script>` for **syntax check**.
   From gnu bash manual https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html

`-n
Read commands but do not execute them; this may be used to check a script for syntax errors. This option is ignored by interactive shells.`

3. Read the script at least once. You can **use echo statement for debug** as mentioned in [answer by user191016](https://superuser.com/a/538278/456388) .

   - Look out for suspicious or danger prone code.
   - e.g. related to rm, commands affecting /dev/sda etc.
4. Always try to run scripts as normal user, **avoid running unknown scripts as root.**
5. You can **define alias** to make command that can modify files as interactive at start of your script
   Example

   `alias rm="rm -i"
   alias cp="cp -i"
   alias mv="mv -i"`

   For stream editors like sed
   `sed -i` (-i modifies the file in place without -i it does a dry run for sed , check man page for details)
   You can copy the full command and run. 
   It just before the actual command it will show the output on screen then use  command to wait for user input to continue.
   Example

   `sed -i <pattern>`
    
   Replace it with 

   `sed <pattern> 
   read -p "Press any key..."
   sed -i <pattern>`

Also it is always suggested to keep backup points in your system so in case of emergency data can be restored.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a little construct I like to use:

```
#!/bin/sh

verbose=false
really=true

# parse arguments
while [ $# -ge 1 ]
do
  case "$1" in
    -v) verbose=true ;;
    -n) really=false; verbose=true ;;
  esac
  shift
done

doCmd() {
  if $verbose; then echo "$@"; fi
  if $really; then "$@"; fi
}

doCmd make foo
doCmd rm -rf /tmp/installdir
doCmd mkdir /tmp/installdir
doCmd whatever
doCmd blah blah
```

Answer (score 3):

Do `set –n`, or append `n` to your existing `set –v` command. 
But since this causes the shell not to evaluate any commands, not even `if` or `while`, you might not get too good a view of the operational flow.

Comment: Thanks. This is a good start, but as you mentioned, it does not let me see the actual flow - where in my real script I have a loop over a list of remote hosts.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to prevent modifications from happening, you can run the script as a user without privileges:

```
sudo -u nobody ./scr.sh
```

In your example, this will execute `FN="filename"` as usual. While it technically executes the command `rm -f ${FN}` as well, nothing will happen if **nobody** doesn't have the necessary permissions to delete the file.

Of course, this will cause problems with conditional workflow. The fact that the `rm` command failed might affect further parts of the script.

Comment: Things we will never understand: Why root is required to run as nobody...

Comment: User "nobody" isn't spevial to the OS, but you can add an entry in the sudoers file that allows passwordless sudo for "nobody".

Comment: I dunno. Seems that the script would terminate because of some error or another before it finished.